# An efficient search for IP addresses using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, grep, zgrep

I would like to find the most efficient regular expression to find three IP addresses in one search, but I'm not sure if there is a more efficient (faster) syntax that I could use.

I've tried searching for them one address at a time, but I'm curious if there is a faster way.

```
zgrep -a -i  192\.168\.1\.(10|23|34) *.* >> Results.txt
```

I'm not getting any errors.  I'm really just trying to find out if there is a faster syntax I could be using.

Comment: How do you include a space in the regex ?

Comment: When you append to the file and use one ip regex at a time it will cause the output file to look different probably. Is that a problem ?

Comment: That command won't work. You should get rid of `-i` since caseless is meaningless for digits and dots and hopefully you don't really have binary files inside your zip files so the `-a` isn't necessary either, but then you need to add `-E` for `|` to work. It'll also match IP addrs like `192.168.1.101` and other strings that contains sections that match that regexp due to no boundaries. Post some sample input (i.e. output of zcat) and expected output if you'd like help. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the ignore case `-i` flag may make it faster. For fixed string matches, such as the 3 possible matches in your example, `grep -F` or `grep -f` is also useful.

You could also use [`sift`](https://sift-tool.org/performance) if you have very large files.

Answer (score 0):

idk about faster (maybe the removal of -a and -i will make a difference, idk) but this will be more accurate as it'll avoid false matches against longer strings that contain your target IP addresses as substrings:

```
zgrep -E '(^|[^0-9])192\.168\.1\.(10|23|34)([^0-9]|$)' file
```

if that's not a concern then this will be faster:

```
printf '192.168.1.10\n192.168.1.23\n192.168.1.34\n' | zgrep -F -f- file
```